# Numbers with a minus sign in a matrix not aligned with the numbers without minus sign

Tags: align, matrices

What should I do to get all the `1` with a minus sign (`-`) in front of them aligned with the other `1` and the `0` in those vectors?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$
v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
v_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\-1 \end{bmatrix},
$$
\end{document}
```

[image: vectors]

Comment: You could do `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
v_1 = \left[\begin{array}{@{}r@{}} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{array}\right], \quad
v_2 = \left[\begin{array}{@{}r@{}} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\0 \end{array}\right], \quad
v_3 = \left[\begin{array}{@{}r@{}} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\-1 \end{array}\right],
\]
\end{document}` but please use `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you've discovered, the `bmatrix` environment centers the cell contents. To achieve right-alignment, you may want to load the `mathtools` package (a superset of the `amsmath` package) and use a `bmatrix*` environment with optional argument `r`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
v_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\-1 \end{bmatrix}.
\]

\[
v_1 = \begin{bmatrix*}[r] 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix*}, \quad
v_2 = \begin{bmatrix*}[r] 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\0 \end{bmatrix*}, \quad
v_3 = \begin{bmatrix*}[r] 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\-1 \end{bmatrix*}.
\]
\end{document}
```